# MySQL, how to select all possible values for a SET column

Tags: php, mysql, types, set

A have database called auctions where i have row called region type SET and values in this SET is region1, region2, region3, region4, region5.
I need to shaw all values.
My code is:

```
<?php 
require('assets/dbconn.php');

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM auctions");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<?php 
echo $row['region'];
?>
```

But it shows me only one value. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to select all possible values for a column type `SET` ? Then you should be able to get them using the following query...

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(COLUMN_TYPE, 'set', '') `values`
FROM 
    information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = '' -- your database name here
AND 
    TABLE_NAME = '' -- your table name here
AND 
    COLUMN_NAME = '' -- your column name
```

You should get a result similar to this one:

```
('region1','region2','region3','region4','region5')
```

Later, using `preg_replace` and `explode` you will be able to convert it to an array (if required)